Broken pipe (write failed) error when publishing large file to CodeArtifact using Gradle
I have a very large (12GB) artifact I'm trying to publish to AWS CodeArtifact using Gradle and every time I run the build, it will fail with the exception below. Other, smaller artifacts in this project upload without issue.
> Could not write to resource 'https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repo/com/my-org/my-artifact/2.0.1/my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz'.
   > Broken pipe (Write failed)

After enabling info logging, it appears that Gradle performs 3 HTTP retries that allow the upload to proceed, 1 at about 1GB, another at 3GB, and a final retry at about 6GB, but after the 4th failure the build fails.
Here are the logs:
» ./gradlew publish --info
<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [40s]
Publishing to repository 'maven' (https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repo/)
Uploading my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz to /maven/my-repo/com/myorg/my-artifact/2.0.1/my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz
> :publishMainPublicationToMavenRepository > my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz > 1.1GiB/11.6 GiB uploaded
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Retrying request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
> :publishMainPublicationToMavenRepository > my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz > 3.3GiB/11.6 GiB uploaded
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> :publishMainPublicationToMavenRepository > my-artifact-2.0.1.tar.gz > 6.2GiB/11.6 GiB uploaded
Retrying request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Retrying request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443: Broken pipe (Write failed)

I can configure Gradle to retry the entire process of uploading the artifact but it will just start the upload over and fail again at the same spot.
There's clearly retry logic happening at a lower level and if I can increase that specific retry count, the upload should complete, but I cannot figure out how/where to configure this retry value or if it's even possible.
Gradle version: 8.10.2
Using maven-publish plugin (latest I believe)
Relevant build.gradle code:
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'distribution'
  id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://us-east-1-codeartifact-domain-0000.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repo/'
    credentials {
      username "aws"
      password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
    }
  }
}

I've tried the following system properties in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with no luck:
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.repository.max.retries=10
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.retry=10
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.network.retry.max.attempts=10

I've tried to find the Gradle code that is performing these retries but I can't tell if this is happening in the maven-publish plugin or at a lower level like in the HTTP client library.

Just noticed that AWS CodeArtifact has maximum file size quotas that may be causing issues for me here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/service-limits.html

In my case the publish/upload to AWS CodeArtifact was failing because of the default quota sizes, documented here: CodeArtifact Quotas. Since the artifact I was attempting to publish was larger than the max "Asset file size" (5 GB) the server was rejecting the request.
I never figured out how to configure the low-level retries during Gradle publish, however, or whether it's even possible to do so.
